# How to choose between sample dataset or user inputted dataset?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app that lets users choose a sample dataset or upload their own data as csv file.

How do I write an `if` `else` or `switch` statement to choose which file gets sent into `dataset <- reactive({`

I'm stuck in this step:

```
           file <- input$file1
                 if (is.null(file)) 
                    return(NULL)
                    read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
                 else {
                    get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
                  }
```

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("dataset", label = "Choose sample dataset", choices = ls("package:datasets")),
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            verbatimTextOutput("summary")
            
        ),

      
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("table")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
        dataset <- reactive({
        
            get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
            
            file <- input$file1
            ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
            
            req(file)
            validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
            
            read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
        })
       
        output$summary <- renderPrint({
            summary(dataset())
        })
       
        output$table <- renderTable({
            dataset()
        })
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you `get(...)` a dataset and ignore the return value? Typically you'd assign this to a variable.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't pay attention to the code when creating a reproducible example which I got from https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-app.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should give a choice to users to pick either own data or dataset from package via `radioButton`.  `conditionPanel` will aid you to display only the selected input.  Then it will be easy to pick either one at any time.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      awesomeRadio(
        inputId = "choosedata",
        label = "Choose own data or package datasets",
        choices = list("Own Data" = "own", "Package Datasets" = "pdata"),
        selected = "own",
        inline = TRUE,
        status = "success",
        width = "300px"
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosedata == 'pdata'",
                       selectInput("dataset", label = "Choose sample dataset", choices = ls("package:datasets"), selected=ls("package:datasets")[[4]])
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.choosedata == 'own'",
                       fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
                       checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
      ),
      
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
      
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dataset <- reactive({
    
    if (input$choosedata == "own") {
      file <- input$file1
      if (!is.null(file)) {
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
        mydata <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
      }else mydata <- NULL
    } else {
      mydata <- get(input$dataset, "package:datasets")
    }
    
    mydata
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    req(dataset())
    summary(dataset())
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    req(dataset())
    dataset()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]